# Convert HTML to PDF using jsPDF

Tags: html, css, angularjs, pdf, jspdf

I have a html page having some static text as well as some controls like dropdownlist and textbox etc along with a button e.g., "Download as pdf".I need to generate a pdf file using angularjs taking the selected value of dropdownlist and value of textbox etc alongwith static content.

The page also uses some external fonts in addition to custom CSS. I need all these in my pdf.

Is it possible in jsPDF?

I tried using fromHTML():- but it only prints the text of text nodes only.
Then I tried using some built-in functions like setFont(), setFontType() etc. I also tried addFont(), but I couldn't figure out what to be passed in font style.

I even tried adding my font in the standardFonts array of addFonts() function in jsPDF library and install my external font in the system(windows folder/fonts). But it's not working.

As jsPDf has some limited designing features only, it is not meeting my requirements.

Is there any other strong tool which I can use?

Comment: fromHTML is kinda limited, check out the new addHTML: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/270

Comment: If you can add everything to your PDF as an image, then [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) may help. You take a screenshot of certain region of the page with a canvas and then put it in the PDF as an image.

Comment: @gab06 But this way my controls are also getting printed.